# Excel VBA Function stops execution before completion without error message

Tags: excel, vba

I set out to write a simple function to determine the length of a string in points. Having googled around I decided to avoid the font metrics problem by having excel do the work for me.

Here is the code.

```
Option Explicit    
Function txtWidthPts(MyText As String) As Integer
    'A cell on a working worksheet has been named "WidthTest" for easy reference & to ensure data is not overwritten.
    'set WidthTest word wrapping off so that strings placed in there aren't wrapped

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With [WidthTest]
        .WrapText = False
        .Value = MyText
'autofit WidthTest
        .Columns.AutoFit
'get the width of the column
        txtWidthPts = .Width
        .ClearContents
    End With

End Function
```

I tested the function by placing it in a cell on a working worksheet thus:
    =txtWidthPts("Test123")
When I have this working I will be using it in code not as a worksheet function.

My problem is that the function does not throw an error and stops execution on the line:

```
.Value = MyText
```

I have placed the code and name into an empty workbook to ensure no interaction with other workbook contents / code.
I have searched extensively and tried various suggestions (DoEvents, Application.Update = False, etc, etc.) to no result.
I have cleared all breakpoints, closed and opened the workbook & restarted. I have tested with options set to Break on All Errors.
No result.

I suspect I am missing something obvious but it has me beat at the moment.

Any and all suggestions will be most welcome.

Comment: You can't modify the Excel environment using a UDF, so you need to test this function from VBA instead.  Just run it from the Immediate Window as, for example, `?txtWidthPts("Test123")`.  Or have a dummy subroutine such as `Sub Test()` `Debug.Print txtWidthPts("Test123")` `End Sub`.

Answer (score 0):

So, @YowE3K was right on the money.  After fixing the error in the original code (Corrected code above) this runs fine from vba. I knew I was missing something obvious.

Curiosity sub-question: the function works as desired and indeed, as @YowE3K observed, it does not modify the Excel environment. However the result returned is dependent on it **appearing** to have modified the Excel environment. Seriously WTF. Just wanting to understand.

Thanks again YoWE3K.

Comment: The function, when invoked from VBA rather than as a UDF, is able to modify the environment, **and does**.  But when invoked as a UDF it will crash on the `.Value = MyText` line (and a crash in a UDF just immediately exits and returns a `#VALUE` error).  I have yet to work out why a UDF **ignores** statements such as `.WrapText = False` but **crashes** on things like `.Value = MyText`.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation. My curiosity sub-question was not quite right. When run from vba the UDF does modify the environment.